# Редирект с index.php на /

Tags: nginx

Задача: нужно убрать возможность ходить на страницы, указывая в адресной строке index.php. Как это сделать в nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

```
if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php$") {
    return 301 $1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот так красивее

```
location ~ /^(?<var>.+?)/index.php$ {
    return  301 $var;
}
```